# how can i validate this emaild "email@-domain.com" with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to validate following email id

```
email@-domain.com
```

for that i am using following regex but it is not validating above email id ,
what type of change in my current regex works for me

here is my regex

```
 /^[A-Za-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\.([A-Za-z]{2,10})$/
```

Comment: `-domain.com` is not a valid domain

Comment: yes but i want to to validate this email address with above regex that i mention

Comment: Validate what? That it's an invalid email adres?

Comment: but when user enter this email address in a input filed it should validate with above regex and above regex doesn't validate this

Comment: You want to allow invalid email addresses?

Comment: no i dont want to allow this but i check my email address with regex and regex allow this email address

Comment: In that case, the link that's provided shows a working regex that does not match your example (ie.shows that the email you've posted is not valid)

Answer (score -1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[-](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(domain|domain2)\.com$
```

or

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,5}/g
```

try this for `email@-domail.com`

Comment: It doesn't match the string the OP said they wanted to match.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15}[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}/g     you can also try it